# How to display variable name itself rather than the value in shell

Tags: shell, variables

For example:

> a=s1;b=s2; for i in $a $b ; do echo $i ; done

I want to get `a and b` NOT `s1 and s2`

How could I do it?

Comment: Only the values of a and b have been fed to $i. That echo command will not be aware of them. However it is technically possible to get the value via other means, perhaps this other stack exchange post will help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129084/in-bash-how-can-i-echo-the-variable-name-not-the-variable-value

Comment: What is this for? It may be you are stuck on a step of a problem someone else has solved already, but in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bash` or `ksh`, indirect parameter expansion is safer than using `eval`.

```
a=s1
b=s2

for i in a b; do
   echo "$i=${!i}"
done
```

If you are using `zsh`, the syntax is slightly different.

```
for i in a b; do
   echo "$i=${(P)i}"
done
```

Other shells might have different syntax; check its documentation for details.

If you are using a shell (e.g. `/bin/sh` or `dash`) without indirect parameter expansion, you'll have to use `eval`:

```
for i in a b; do
    eval "echo $i=\$$i"
done
```

Here, `eval` is safe because you had explicit control over the value of `i`. In general, any parameters expanded in the argument to `eval` should be validated to ensure you don't execute code you didn't expect to.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

> a=s1;b=s2; for i in \$a \$b ; do echo $i ; done

This will get `a` and `b`

If you also want to use the value, try this:

> a=s1;b=s2; for i in \$a \$b ; do eval "echo $i" ; done

This will get `s1` and `s2`